# What's the meaning of "lay out" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I came across the phrase in this passage of an article on The Hollywood Walk of Fame:

> Having a star on the Hollywood Walk of Fame is a huge honor. Specific requirements are **laid out** for those actors, musicians, directors, producers and others who earn a spot on the walk.

This is the definition of *lay out* from OALD :

> 3 to present a plan, an argument, etc. clearly and carefully

But what does *present* mean in this definition? Does it mean: [to show or offer something for other people to look at or consider?](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/present_3) or [to show or describe something/somebody in a particular way?](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/present_3)

Comment: It can also mean *to make a detailed plan*, which is the case here. It simply means that such (detailed) requirements exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Present*, in this case, is your first definition: *to show or offer something for other people to look at or consider*

In this case, though, I think the best definition of *laid out* is a combination of:

> [***lay out***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lay_out#English) : (transitive) *to concoct; think up*

and your: *3 to present a plan*

In other words the requirements that an actor or actress must meet in order to earn a spot on "The Walk" were thought up by someone (or some group) and presented to the world.